# Why Jquery Ajax get method implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What I want is when i press the button Sweet alert pop up and given URL need to be invoked. i just try to JQuery ajax get method. following code segment not working what i want.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.0/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Accept your promotion</button>
<script>
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/update/status/"+pcode+"/ACCEPT", function myFunction(){
        $( ".result" ).html( data );
        swal(
            'Congratulations!',
            'You successfully accept your promotion',
            'success'
        )
    })
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Your get request isn't being called. Wrap it in a function which is triggered by the `onclick`

Comment: @BrettGregson I did`t get you. actually im very new to this. can you please help me with the code changes

Comment: @JonathanLam when i press the button  neither  sweet alert  poops up nor linked link called.

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` event is calling a function called `myFunction()` which isn't defined. Wrap your get request in a function definition:

```
var pcode = "test"; // Not sure where you're defining pcode?

myFunction = function(){ // Define your function
    $.get( "http://localhost:8080/update/status/"+pcode+"/ACCEPT", function(data){
        // Your get request is complete
        $( ".result" ).html( data );
        swal('Congratulations!','You successfully accept your promotion','success');
    });
};
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/r5uvwj7o/

Change the URL from `"http://echo.jsontest.com/"` back to your URL `"http://localhost:8080/update/status/"+pcode+"/ACCEPT"`

Comment: Sir, i tried this . But not working as i mentioned above.

Comment: Open your console in your browser, what error are you getting? What is `pcode`? Where is it being defined?

Comment: Error is pcode not defined. shall i try with working url like google.com like such?

Comment: The URL that you're making the get request to has a variable called pcode. You can change the URL to google.com, or check my updated example above, I've added pcode but your application isn't going to work as expected since I'm not sure what pcode is or where it's supposed to be coming from. I recommend doing a quick basic JS tutorial otherwise you're going to struggle all the way with this. It'll be a couple hours of time well spent. I recommend starting here https://javascript.info/first-steps

Comment: Actually this is a small part of a huge project. system based on sending emails to employees who having some promotions. this is in the mail body when employee received email he/ she can accept that promotion by pressing that button.if someone press that button Spring API will update a database column to Boolean 1 .so pcode is somewhat a attribute use to identify a employee separate manner . did you get my point sir.

Comment: Let's continue this in chat - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179840/52280425